# We have created the knative serverless application in GCP.And we are trying to accesss it by using istio mesh

Tags: istio, knative, istio-gateway

But we are getting status code 404 while accessing the API.

Implemented below steps:

1. Pointed domain URL to istio load balancer external IP.
2. Applyed a VirtualService that maps its route destinations to istio-ingressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local

Yaml file :

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: entry-route
  namespace: vulcan
spec:
  # gateways:
  # - istio-ingressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
  hosts:
  - ktest.xxx.com
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/atlas/*"
    rewrite:
      authority: k-atlas-service.vulcan.xxx.com
    route:
      - destination:
          host: istio-ingressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
        weight: 100
```

Comment: Hi, which endpoint gives you this error? What is your expected situation? Where is your application? Which version of Kubernetes and Istio did you use?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Domain Mapping API](https://knative.dev/docs/developer/serving/services/custom-domains/)? That API is designed to make this task easier and more consistent across the different Knative networking implementations.

If that API isn't available, [these instructions for Istio](https://knative.dev/docs/serving/samples/knative-routing-go/#apply-custom-routing-rule) might provide a working example. I suspect that you may need to either target the Knative-internal VirtualService or the internal url for the Knative Service in the VirtualService you posted above.